# Best method for resample and reproject large set of data

Tags: r, netcdf4, cdo-climate, nco

I got all set of daily data from IMERG (precipitation) from 2005 to 2020. (5947 files).

I need to made this:

- clip the data for my interest area for reduce the size of the total file. **done!**

  `cdo sellonlatbox`
- Reproject the files to EPSG:31983 (UTM) **and** resize the pixel to 25mx25m. ***Stuck on this!!***

Now i'm using the `projectRaster` from R, but it is too lazy !!

Someone have some tips?

i can use python, R, NCO, CDO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the future people: Use `gdalwarp` function for it.

Example:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:31983 -tr 25 25 -te 512125 7738250 660700 8061650 -r near input.nc output.nc
```

Explanation:

`-s_srs EPSG:4326` input srs

`-t_srs EPSG:31983` output srs

`-tr 25 25` is the spatial resolution

`-te 512125 7738250 660700 8061650` is the new extent acording to `EPSG:31983`

`-r near` resample method

Comment: hi Bryan, this answer would be more useful if you gave the full command along with a little explanation :-)

Comment: @AdrianTompkins. What about now?